# How to add additional custom jvm argument?

Tags: java, jnlp

I am trying to perform instrumentation on JNLP.

The java-vm-args option does not work because it only allow specified set of argument.

I'm trying use "Xbootclasspath" , "agentpath", -XX:-UseSplitVerifier and -DOPtions

JNLP Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html

Setting JAVAWS_VM_ARGS is not a good option too

http://www.yourkit.com/docs/90/help/profiling_webstart.jsp

---

I start it using jnlp but I'm open to options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to fall back to setting the JAVAWS_VM_ARGS.
Setting other options than the allowed ones could result in a security breach, that is why they are filtered.

If you launch an applet inside a browser, then you could set the 'Runtime Parameters' in the Java Control Panel (tab 'Java').

How do you start your application?